# How to make my site's categories appear in Google results?

Tags: search

I would like my site's categories to appear in the Google results.
For example the [bbc.co.uk has the categories "News","Learning English"](http://www.google.gr/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=new%20york%20times#pq=bbc&hl=el&cp=4&gs_id=k&xhr=t&q=bbc.co.uk&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=bbc.&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=572c5ca11ba69056&biw=1366&bih=682), etc.

Is there any module for this? Has this to do with RDF, microformats, or rich snippnets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal is fantastic for building SEO sites but still I think you can not do this. 
Google does this.
The official source is:
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334

Answer (score 1):

Sites with Sitelinks - the name for the indented category listings you see on Google search results - seem to share some characteristics, from what I've found when trying to achieve the same:

- Strong presence (both in terms of search traffic and search term, particularly for brands)
- Diverse and natural backlinks to the site and pages
- Thoughtful information architecture/ site architecture

I would say that the first point is the most important, as Google seems to imply 'authority' with the search results it returns in the Sitelinks format. The subsequent two points *may* be entirely incidental characteristics - but they definitely don't do any harm!

There's nothing particular to Drupal about Sitelinks, though. Whether it's Wordpress, Magento, Drupal or a custom-built site, Sitelinks are platform-agnostic.